# How to combine groupby results without NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['10', '20'], ['10', '15'], ['15', '14']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['dt', 'ct'])
df.groupby('dt')['dt'].count()
```

returns

```
dt
10    2
15    1
```

and

```
df.groupby('ct')['ct'].count()
```

returns

```
ct
14    1
15    1
20    1
```

and then when I combine results

```
df.groupby('ct')['ct'].count() + df.groupby('dt')['dt'].count()
```

it returns

```
10    NaN
14    NaN
15    2.0
20    NaN
```

But I want to get the following:

```
10    2
14    1
15    2.0
20    1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stack` + `value_counts` instead of two groupbys

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

```
10    2
15    2
20    1
14    1
dtype: int64
```

---

If you have more than these columns, index first

```
df[['dt', 'ct']].stack().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data = [['10', '20'], ['10', '15'], ['15', '14']] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['dt', 'ct'])
df2= df1.groupby('ct')['ct'].count()
df3= df1.groupby('dt')['dt'].count()
print df2.append(df3)
```